# Using equation from Google lens

Tags: math-mode, ocr

Apologies if this question is off topic.

I am trying to create a maths test paper for my daughter by scanning questions from her textbook.

I found that Google lens can ocr the equation quite accurately but when pasting it into an editor its all messed up.

For example in the screenshot below the question is correctly identified
[image: Google lebs screenshot of an equation]

But the text copied is as follows:

```
Q.7. Prove that: 
sqrt(2 + sqrt(2 + 2cos 4theta)) = 2cos theta
```

Which is not very useful.

Has anyone attempted this before with any success? Any other approach to reach my objective?

Thanks and regards!!

Comment: Offtopic, but try theta=pi/2 in the formula.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try use [Mathpix Snip](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mathpix.snip) for Android. it's free

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Its working perfectly.